# What is the type of data returned in this code ? If this is the instance then how do we get value using this returned value?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

Code :

```
class A:
    class B:

        def __init__(self,value):
            self.value=value
    def get(self,value):
        return self.B(value)

a=A()
print(a.get(5))
```

Output:

```
<__main__.A.B object at 0x7f39df4dc5d0>
```

What is data type of data being returned.Is it the pointer address or the instance itself ? and how do we get the instance(I want the value) using this returned output ?

Any help is appriciated

Answer (score 0):

When you call `a.get(5)` you're calling the constructor of the class `B` inside of a specific instance of `A` and returning a newly created instance of `B`.

We can verify this quite simply:

```
>>> type(a.get(5))
<class '__main__.A.B'>
```

However every time we call the above code, we are not getting the same instance of `B`:

```
>>> a.get(5) == a.get(5)
False
```

We are giving the same input to the constructor, but because they are two separately created instances, they do not equate to each other.

We can however fetch the value of the new instance simply by calling the attribute `value`:

```
>>> a.get(5).value
5
```

Here we can do another comparison, and we can see that it now returns `True`, because the values contained in the attributes are the same:

```
>>> a.get(5).value == a.get(5).value
True
```

Comment: In positional list made up by doubly linked list how do we give the position of the element

Comment: when we create a new node(instance) we return the positon of it

Comment: in a book i saw returning istance like in the above code

Comment: how do we store these positions

Comment: If you're trying to implement Doubly-linked-list then I think that is a question all for itself. You can find an old question about trying to implement it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803920/doubly-linked-list-in-python). Just going from "how can I access a attribute of an object" to "how can I implement this complex data-structure" is quite a big leap.